# ASP.Net MVC 6 route error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have ASP.Net MVC 6 application

I added a route like bellow:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
        defaults: new {Controllers="Statics", action="Index"}
        );

});
```

but I get error like bellow:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The route parameter 'controller' 
>   has both an inline default value and an explicit default value specified. 
>   A route parameter cannot contain an inline default value when a default value is specified explicitly, consider removing one of them.

Any advise?

Comment: Either remove the defaults or the inline default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and testing I found a good post: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing

and I updated my routs like bellow it works perfect

```
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "route2",
              template: "statics",
              defaults: new { controller = "Departments", action = "Index" }

             );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "route3",
               template: "statics/SYears",
               defaults: new { controller = "SYears", action = "Index" }
            );
            /*
              routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                defaults: new {controller="Statics", action="Index"}
                );

            */
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're attempting to define both an inline default value and an explicit default value. When defining the `template` argument the `=` operator will assign `defaults`, but you're then attempting to explicitly define defaults on the next line. Consider the following:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        // Notice the removal of the defaults from the template?
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new {Controllers="Statics", action="Index"}
        );

});
```

An alternative is define a `template` with inline `defaults` and then omit the `defaults` line altogether like so:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        // Notice how we assign the defaults inline, and omit the defaults line?
        template: "{controller=Statics}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what you need to do

You can either remove the inline default values

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new {controller="Statics", action="Index"}
        );

});
```

Or remove the explicit default value template:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Statics}/{action=Index}/{id?}"                
        );
});
```

Comment: I have created a folder inside controllers with title Statics where I put some static controllers how can I get to these controllers functions

Comment: Doesn't matter where you put them. Once they follow the convention you setup in your routes.

Comment: This answer addresses the error stated in your original post.